# segmentation fault while writing to a file

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am getting segmentation Fault while writing into file , code is below

I am opening a file in binary mode . I have memcpy many structure to an array and then writing the data into file (named as sample.avi)

```
ofstream AVI;
AVI.open("sample.avi",ios::binary);

if(!AVI)
{
   cout << "AVI file not opening"<<endl;
   return 0;
}

long long int size = 0;
size = sizeof(List) + sizeof(List) + sizeof(AVIMainHeader) + sizeof(List) + sizeof(AVIStreamHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) + sizeof(List);
 cout << size;
uint8_t *AVIFile = new uint8_t[300];

List riff = MakeRiffHeader();
List hdrl = MakeHdrlHeader();
AVIMainHeader avih = MakeAvihHeader();
List strl = MakeStrlHeader();
AVIStreamHeader strh = MakeStrhHeader();
BitmapInfoHeader bit = MakeBitHeader();
List movi = MakeMoviHeader();

long long int length1 = 0;

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&riff, sizeof(List));
length1 += sizeof(List);

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&hdrl, sizeof(List));
length1 += sizeof(List);

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&avih, sizeof(AVIMainHeader));
length1 += sizeof(AVIMainHeader);

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&strl, sizeof(List));
length1 += sizeof(List);

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&strh, sizeof(AVIStreamHeader));
length1 += sizeof(AVIStreamHeader);

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&bit, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader));
length1 += sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader);

memcpy(&AVIFile[length1], (const void*)&movi, sizeof(List));
length1 += sizeof(List);

AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(AVIFile),length1);

Chunk vidf;
vidf.Ckid = MakeFourCC("00db");
vidf.CkSize = 2048 * 1537;

AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vidf), sizeof(vidf));
AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(red), 2048 * 1537);

AVI.close();
return 0;
```

the Line from where i have start `writing(AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(AVIFILE), length1))` and below lines seems like the source for segmentation fault (as if we comment it , it is not giving fault).

please kindly point out where i am wrong

EDIT :

```
uint8_t *BUFFER = new uint8_t[length];                   
uint8_t *BUFFER1 = new uint8_t[(3 * length) / 2];
uint8_t *final_image = new uint8_t[(3 * length) / 2];
uint8_t *red = new uint8_t[2048 * 1546];            
uint8_t *green1 = new uint8_t[2048 * 1546];         
uint8_t *green2 = new uint8_t[2048 * 1546];         
uint8_t *blue = new uint8_t[2048 * 1546];
```

Comment: Why do you copy to an array first and the write the array? Why not write the structures directly? `AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(riff),sizeof riff); AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(hdrl),sizeof hdrl); ...`

Comment: okay , i will try that

Comment: I don't think it's the bug (unless your array of 300 bytes is not big enough).

Comment: but i need to store video frames after that and then keep a offset for reading , so thought it would be better to do it in array

Comment: What is `red`? I don't see any declaration for that.

Comment: You don't `delete[]` the array, so that is a memory leak (but still not the source of your bug).

Comment: It's much more robust to use `sizeof(variable)` than `sizeof(type_of_variable)`. And you don't need to cast to `void*`.

Comment: i have just tried that , but it is again giving segmentation fault, no idea :(

Comment: Still would like to see the declaration for `red`, that's my strongest suspicion at the moment.

Comment: Why do you allocate 300 bytes and not simply `new uint8_t[size]`?

Comment: @john red is the red is an array which contains the video frame , i haven't pasted the whole code here ,

Comment: @Devendrashaktawat You can post the declaration. I want to see the type.

Comment: @molbdnila , okay  i will change it , thanks

Comment: @rustyx As it happens if you look closely the size calculation is wrong `sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader)` is included twice, but only written once.

Comment: @john please see the edit i have made

Comment: @Devendrashaktawat there's your problem

Comment: @rustyx , how does it affect the segmentation fault ,

Comment: @john where ?? , can u please point it out

Comment: @Devendrashaktawat see my answer

Comment: Post a [mcve].  You have dynamic memory management going on, and we have no idea if you have corrupted memory in some way.  Better to have used `std::vector<char>` and/or `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead of issuing `new []` calls (without any sign of a `delete []`) being done.

Comment: Thanks PaulMckenzie , actuall the problem was in MakeAVIMainHeader which was declared in  some other file

Answer (score 0):

```
AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&red), 2048 * 1537);
```

should be

```
AVI.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(red), 2048 * 1537);
```

When you have a pointer you don't need to add `&` to get the address being pointed to, you just use the pointer itself.

Comment: sorry john , it didn't helped

Comment: no matter how am i writing into file it is just giving segmentation fault

Comment: Well the change above is definitely necessary to get a working program, even if it doesn't solve your crash. What I'd recommend is removing small parts of your code until the crash goes away. If you can find the smallest possible section of code that when it's removed stops the crash, then the bug is **probably** in that secition of code.

Comment: Okay i surely change it . As i said in my question , if i comment the line  from where i have start writing into file it stops giving error (from line AVIFILE. write(retinterpret_cast<char*>), length1) till the AVI.close();

Comment: thanks john , The hit and trail method worked , the problem was in MakeAVIMainheader fucntion which was in some other file , But thanks